# Converting doc files to text files

Tags: python, text, ms-word, converters, document

I have a list of MS word doc files in a directory. The directory also contains sub folders. I'm trying to convert all the document files in the directory to text files. Is there any way that I can do that without going much deeper into programming. Any shortcut or something like that?

Comment: If you don't want to go into programming, maybe you should not ask on Stackoverflow... Anyway, it seems to me that you are mostly looking for a converter.

Comment: yeah. Any idea of some converter which would be helpful to me. I need to convert around 11,000 files

Comment: Please take a moment to read the site guidelines in the [help] for asking questions on Stack Overflow. You'll notice that asking for tools, libraries, converters, etc. is off-topic...

Comment: `ibreoffice --headless --convert-to pdf *.doc` may do the job.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek could you please explain in detail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to convert multiple Word files to other formats, like TXT, RTF, HTML or PDF, run the script below (from MS Word; hit Alt+F11 and paste the code into the window that opens).

```
Option Explicit On

Sub ChangeDocsToTxtOrRTFOrHTML()
    'with export to PDF in Word 2007
    Dim fs As Object
    Dim oFolder As Object
    Dim tFolder As Object
    Dim oFile As Object
    Dim strDocName As String
    Dim intPos As Integer
    Dim locFolder As String
    Dim fileType As String
    On Error Resume Next

    locFolder = InputBox("Enter the folder path to DOCs", "File Conversion", "C:\Users\your_path_here\")
    Select Case Application.Version
        Case Is < 12
            Do
                fileType = UCase(InputBox("Change DOC to TXT, RTF, HTML", "File Conversion", "TXT"))
            Loop Until (fileType = "TXT" Or fileType = "RTF" Or fileType = "HTML")
        Case Is >= 12
            Do
                fileType = UCase(InputBox("Change DOC to TXT, RTF, HTML or PDF(2007+ only)", "File Conversion", "TXT"))
            Loop Until (fileType = "TXT" Or fileType = "RTF" Or fileType = "HTML" Or fileType = "PDF")
    End Select

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set oFolder = fs.GetFolder(locFolder)
    Set tFolder = fs.CreateFolder(locFolder & "Converted")
    Set tFolder = fs.GetFolder(locFolder & "Converted")

    For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
        Dim d As Document
        Set d = Application.Documents.Open(oFile.Path)
        strDocName = ActiveDocument.Name
        intPos = InStrRev(strDocName, ".")
        strDocName = Left(strDocName, intPos - 1)
        ChangeFileOpenDirectory tFolder
        Select Case fileType
            Case Is = "TXT"
                strDocName = strDocName & ".txt"
                ActiveDocument.SaveAs FileName:=strDocName, FileFormat:=wdFormatText
        Case Is = "RTF"
                strDocName = strDocName & ".rtf"
                ActiveDocument.SaveAs FileName:=strDocName, FileFormat:=wdFormatRTF
        Case Is = "HTML"
                strDocName = strDocName & ".html"
                ActiveDocument.SaveAs FileName:=strDocName, FileFormat:=wdFormatFilteredHTML
        Case Is = "PDF"
                strDocName = strDocName & ".pdf"
                ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:=strDocName, ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF
        End Select
        d.Close
        ChangeFileOpenDirectory oFolder
    Next oFile
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: That helped a lot man.

Comment: Great.  Happy to help.